# What is the `<>` symbol in brightscript?

Tags: if-statement, roku, brightscript

I see a lesser than and greater than side by side in Brightscript. What does that mean? Not equals perhaps?

```
if item <> invalid
    screen.SetContent(item)
endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most languages with `<>` it means not equals. It dates back to the BASIC language, but it can be found in php, vb, sql, C, actionscript, everywhere.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I usually see != in php for not equals, so I didn't know.